# Looking for PDF map downloading capability in OpenGeo GXP

Tags: openlayers, boundless-suite

I am looking for a plugin to [OpenGeo GXP](http://workshops.opengeo.org/gxp/basic/resources.html) in order to download maps in PDF format.

Could you help me?

Comment: I hope that a few readability edits I made to this question may convince the downvoters that it is legitimate and deserving of better treatment.

Answer (score 1):

That's out of scope for GXP - you'll need to find another tool for PDF downloads.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the GeoExt printing examples which work with GeoServer and MapFish.

http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/print-form.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution tested with the OpenGeo client sdk is [here:](https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/doubts_about_the_use_of_print_from_openlayers_ready_gxp)

Best luck,
Tudor

Comment: tudorbarascu the link you provided is inactive , not found. the resources are down. do you know any other  example working in open geosuite 4.6 gxp ?